# Oracle SQL: select a count from one table, narrow the selection with subquery from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Goal:  return a count of people who logged in on date X by role, or by certain role exclusions.

And I've done this in various ways in the past, usually by selecting what I want, then using an app language (php, etc..) to loop over the result set, querying the second table.  I'm looking for a more efficient, perhaps pure sql way of doing this.

```
LoginTable
+--------------------+
| userName loginDate |
+--------------------+
| jason 08/15/16     |
| jason 09/01/16     |
| john 08/15/16      |
| john 09/04/16      |
| cindy 08/15/16     |
+--------------------+
RoleTable
+--------------------+
| userName role|
+--------------------+
| jason admin        |
| jason student      |
| jason employee     |
| john  employee     |
| john admin         |
| cindy student      |
| cindy hr           |
| cindy finance      |
+--------------------+
```

Is there a pure oracle SQL way of doing this, without resorting to further post-processing?

For instance, one question might be:
Who logged in on 08/15/16, who had the employee role, but not the student role.

The answer should be john.

Select userName from LoginTable
where loginDate = 08/15/16 and LoginTable.userName in (Select userName from RoleTable where role = employee and role <> student)

That query of course would not work.

Is there a pure sql way to do this, or should I go back to loops/post-processing or perhaps a temp table?

I am looking for efficiency, since these tables will have millions of rows.

Comment: editing, trying to get the tables right.

Comment: You changed the question, thereby rendering my answer incorrect.  You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Here is the answer to the updated question, which is substantially different than what was originally asked (q.v. below)

You can use conditional aggregation over users in the `RoleTable` to determine which users had the `employee` role but not the `student` role.  Then you can further restrict this to users who logged in on `08/15/16`:

```
SELECT t1.userName
FROM RoleTable t1
INNER JOIN LoginTable t2
    ON t1.userName = t2.userName
WHERE t1.loginDate = TO_DATE('08/15/16', 'DD/MM/YY')
GROUP BY t1.userName
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t1.role = 'employee' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.role = 'student'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

**Note:** The question was changed substantially since when I first gave this answer.  The original question was give a count of students who logged on a certain date, for each role.

```
SELECT t1.role,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t2.userName IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS peopleCount
FROM RoleTable t1
LEFT JOIN LoginTable t2
    ON t1.userName = t2.userName
WHERE t1.loginDate = '08/15/16'
GROUP BY t1.role
```

Comment: He wants name of person, having specified role.

Comment: @sql_dummy He changed his question about one hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT userName 
  FROM LoginTable 
 WHERE loginDate = TO_DATE('08/15/16', 'DD/MM/YY')
    -- include
   AND userName IN (SELECT userName FROM RoleTable WHERE role = 'employee')
    -- exclude
   AND userName NOT IN (SELECT userName FROM RoleTable WHERE role = 'student')
```